# Почему при обучении нейросети не нагружается видеокарта

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, pytorch, cuda

Пробую обучить нейросеть по своим данным
вроде все настроил

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO('yolov8m.pt')
results = model.train(data = 'data.yaml', epochs = 100, imgsz=640)
```

Программа увидела видеокарту

```
Ultralytics YOLOv8.1.24  Python-3.9.18 torch-2.2.1+cu121 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU, 4096MiB)
```

все работает, эпохи грузятся
Мне стало интересно, как сильно обучение загружает видеокарту, открыл диспетчер
Видеокарта не загружена вообще, максимум 5% иногда прыгает, в основном загружена оперативка, консоль жрет 5гб

что-то мне подсказывает, что так не должно быть

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, в данном случае нейросеть загружает карту по особому(у меня не правильное пониманиие "загруженности") и в диспетчере задач, во вкладке производительность у графиков можно выбрать какой именно процесс они будут отображать.

там появится возможность выбора "cuda" и вот уже тут будет показана загруженность.

для меня остается вопросом, почему это никак не затрагивает общую загруженность карты, даже когда cuda упирается в 100%